# Where is the difference between between memory header in VS2010 and VS2012 regarding smart pointers?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, c++11

There seems to be a different in the declaration of smart pointers (shared_ptr, unique_ptr and weakptr) between VS2010 and VS2012 header file versions.

As far as I understand it, e.g. shared_ptr is now (through C++11) part of the std namespace. Is it **also still** part of the tr1 namespace for compability issues? IF so, how is this achieved?

Thank you

Comment: `namespace std { struct bob {}; namespace tr1 { using ::std::bob; } }` would be one way.

Comment: Hm, you're right. I took a look into the header, there is something like that: namespace tr1 { ... using _STD shared_ptr ...} I guess _STD is somewhere defined as ::std:: or something ?!?

Comment: Yes, exactly. In earlier versions, they did it the other way around, defining the types in `std::tr1` and then `using tr1::stuff;` inside `std`.

Comment: Ok, so I think my question is answered. Would somebody post it as answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In header `<memory>` they defined the `tr1` namespace like this:

```
namespace tr1 { // TR1 additions
using _STD allocate_shared;
using _STD bad_weak_ptr;
using _STD const_pointer_cast;
using _STD dynamic_pointer_cast;
using _STD enable_shared_from_this;
using _STD get_deleter;
using _STD make_shared;
using _STD shared_ptr;
using _STD static_pointer_cast;
using _STD swap;
using _STD weak_ptr;
}   // namespace tr1
```

`_STD` is defined in yvals.h as

```
#if defined(__cplusplus)
 #define _STD_BEGIN namespace std {
 #define _STD_END       }
 #define _STD   ::std::
```

Comment: A, great. The 'mysterious' _STD define is explained, too. Thanks!